# How to instantiate a property with its parent instance at declare time

Tags: c#, class, instance

Here's my code:

```
 var Operations = new List<Operation>
 {
     new Operation
     {
         Date = DateTime.Now,
         OperationId = 0,
         OperationType = OperationType.Entry,
         OperationVehicles = new List<OperationVehicle>
         {
             new OperationVehicle { Vehicle = vehicle},
         }
     },
     new Operation
     {
         Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
         OperationId = 1,
         OperationType = OperationType.Exit,
         OperationVehicles = new List<OperationVehicle>
         {
             new OperationVehicle { Vehicle = vehicle, /* Operation = ???*/},
         }
     }
 };
```

`OperationVehicle` class has a virtual public property of type `Operation` that I want to instantiate it with its parent Operation instance at this stage. Well, I think at this time the Operation may be not created yet. Is there a way to do this in C# or do I have to do classic affectation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Section 7.6.10.2 in the [C# Language spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all) (emphasis mine).

> An object initializer consists of a sequence of member initializers,
>   enclosed by { and } tokens and separated by commas. Each member
>   initializer must name an accessible field or property of the object
>   being initialized, followed by an equals sign and an expression or an
>   object initializer or collection initializer. It is an error for an
>   object initializer to include more than one member initializer for the
>   same field or property. **It is not possible for the object
>   initializer to refer to the newly created object it is initializing.**

If I understand your question correctly then it's not possible to refer to the new object within the object initialization so it's not possible to do what you're trying as `vehicle` is not accessible at this point.

Comment: You fully understood my question.Thanks!